# Windows Server Essentials 2016 - how and when is the primordial pool created?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2016

I have installed WSE 2016 to do client backups as a replacement for an old Windows Home Server. I started with one disk with a 120GB partition for the system and about 600GB for data. I now need to add a second drive but I can't figure out how to do it.

According to research, before I set up a storage space on the WSE dashboard I need to set up a storage pool in Server Manager, but no drives appear when I try to create a storage pool (I experimented by adding a 500GB USB drive with no partitions). I can see the new disk when I look at File and Server Storage, Volumes, Disk.  Apparently, no primordial pool got created.  I've seen the prerequisites in the documentation and in a post in this forum and I think I've met those.

So, here are my questions:

1. How/when does the primordial pool get created?
2. Did I make a mistake by formatting both partitions prior to starting the          install?  I can do the install again - should I just create the
   partition to be used for the C: drive (120GB according to the
   documentation) and leave the rest unformatted until after the
   install    completes?  Is it likely/possible that the primordial
   pool would be    created at that point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got a new 1TB SSD and did the install again without creating partitions ahead of time.  When I got to the place in the install where it asked where to put the operating system, I told it to make a partition with 120GB of the unallocated space.  When the install completed I brought up Server Manager and now the primordial pool exists!  Next I'll add another drive (which shouldn't be a problem this time).

BTW, my first install encountered the "stuck at 17% and 39%" problem requiring the starting of the WSE Management Service but that didn't happen this time.  Also, in the days after the install that service would occasionally stop but that hasn't happened so far with this new install.

The forum bot thinks my answer isn't clear enough?!  I don't know what else to say - I was unable to create a primordial pool after my first install attempt so I re-installed using a completely blank (all unallocated space) disk.  It looks like the appearance of that unallocated allowed the pool to be created.

Also, in the first install the windows updates weren't working so I had to download them manually and install.  With this second installation, it's working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).